# phpseclib keysize is calculated wrong

Tags: key, phpseclib

On site http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/crypt/examples.html
If you choose options on image shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvCoJ.jpg
it outputs key like "abcdefghijklmnopijklmnopqrstuvwxqrstuvwxyz123456yz3456" and it's length is 54 chars, means 54 byte. Which is 54*6bit = 432 bit.

Is not this wrong?

Comment: When I do it the key it shows me is `$cipher->setKey('abcdefghijklmnopijklmnopqrstuvwxyz3456');` What browser are you using? Link: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/crypt/examples.html#aes,ecb,outer,k256,kr128,b128,key,padding, SS: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uYbYD.png

Comment: @neubert I am using chromium.

Comment: Also It is not important. Your key length is 38 chars long. This means 38*8=304 bit. Is not it?

Comment: Hmmm - looks like you're right. Superficially it looks like it's the key is the alphabet + some numbers at the end but it's not. Letters i-p are repeated twice. Maybe that was intended but my guess is that it's more likely a bug in the JS that the website is using - I'll submit a bug report and see if that can't be fixed up.

Comment: If you wish to support you, I can make a bug report too for speeding things up.

Comment: Looks like it was updated.

Comment: Yes I think so. Developer team had updated codes.